# Ok() is handling error message instead of Err() in match expression

Tags: rust, command

I execute commands:

```rust
use std::process::Command;

pub fn search(query: &str, flag: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let command = format!("xdotool search --onlyvisible {} {}", flag, query);
    let output = Command::new("sh").arg("-c").arg(command).output();

    match output {
        Ok(o) => {
            println!("Success message: {:?}", o);

            String::from_utf8_lossy(&o.stdout)
                .lines()
                .map(|s| s.to_owned())
                .collect()
        }
        Err(err) => {
            eprintln!(
                "Error message: {:?}",
                String::from_utf8_lossy(&err.to_string().as_bytes())
                    .trim()
                    .to_owned()
            );
            Vec::new()
        }
    }
}
```

If I use a wrong `flag`, I get an error message, but it's being handled of `Ok()` in the `search()` function:

```rust
Success message: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "search: unrecognized ...
```

Why is this? And how to make `Err()` handle the error message instead?

Comment: `String::from_utf8_lossy(v.to_string().as_bytes())`? This is a strange and unnecessary beast.

Comment: result of command is for execution error, the program run correctly and report a user input error

Comment: And the `to_owned()` there is also unnecessary.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I changed it to: `String::from_utf8_lossy(&o.stderr));`

Comment: @alexchenco I'm very curious how you managed to do that, when you don't have access to `stderr` or `o` at all.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Ah, that's after I implemented your suggestion. That's in the `Ok()` arm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Err` returned from `output()` means **spawning the process failed**. It means nothing about the success/failure of the process itself. You need to check the [`ExitStatus`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Output.html#structfield.status):

```rust
if !o.status.success() {
    // Probably print stderr and bail.
}
```